# Django-Allauth, Multiple login redirect url

Tags: django

I have a question, how can I add more than one LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings or in views for my differents users.
For example, I have: Administrators, Human Resources, Teachers, students... etc
and for each I need redirect to a different url, panel admin for Admin etc.
I need add groups? or not?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-allauth` get the login redirect URL from method `get_login_redirect_url` defined in account adapter you can define your custom adapter and override this:

**my_app/adapter.py**

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        url = super(AccountAdapter, self).get_login_redirect_url(request)
        user = request.user
        '''
        # pseudocode, change it to actual logic
        # check user role and return a different URL
        role = get_user_role(user)
        if role == 'student':
            url = student_login_redirect_url
        if role == 'teacher':
            url = teacher_login_redirect_url
        '''
        return url
```

Now tell allauth to use our custom adapter by defining the `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` in `settings.py`:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'my_app.adapter.AccountAdapter'
```